# A minor change in ASP.NET default _LoginPartial view not working

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my ASP.NET Core project using `Individual User Accounts` I've made a minor change by adding a Role check to display the `Register` link (that, by default, is displayed on the upper right corner) to display only if the user is logged in and is in the Admin Role so that only admin, after logging, can add other users to the system as well. But for some reason, the following part not displaying the `Register` link even if you are logging in as an Admin who is in the `AdminRole`. I've checked, by placing a break point, that `User.IsInRole("AdminRole")` evaluates to true:

**_LoginPartial**:

```
@model ABCTest.Models.ABCTest.CurrentYear
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using ABCTest.Models

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" method="post" id="logoutForm">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Welcome @UserManager.GetUserName(User), you are working with year @Model.CurrentYr - @(@Model.CurrentYr + 1)</a></li>                
         </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-right" style="list-style:none;">
            @{bool bTest = User.IsInRole("AdminRole");
                if (bTest)
                {
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register</a></li>
                }
             }            
            <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log off</button></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

**Part that is not displaying even when the logged-in user is in AdminRole**:

```
@{bool bTest = User.IsInRole("AdminRole");
      if (bTest)
      {
         <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Add User</a></li>
      }
  }
```

**UPDATE**

1. I've verified that user  Admin is in `AdminRole`
2. When I step through the code, it takes me to the `if (bTest)` part that tooltip displays as `true`, after that I can see cursor goes to `{` part of if statement but then it jumps to `}` part of if statement. But that probably is happening since `<li>....<\li>` does not have the c# code inside it.

**UPDATE 2**:

Even if I hard code `if(bTest){...}` as `if(true){...}` the app does not display the `Register` link. **So, I think the crux of the issue is**: Why app is ignoring the `Register` link inside the `if statement`

Comment: @JoshMein Thank you for trying to help. I've added an `UPDATE` section to my post to answer your questions that my help others, as well.

Comment: try get rid of the variable and do @if (User.IsInRole("AdminRole")){}

Comment: @Steve Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I've already tried that. I even tried hard coding the `if(bTest){...}` as `if(true){...}` but it does not work. Please see my **UPDATE 2**

Comment: can you look into the dom element and see if the li is indeed not rendered?

Comment: @Steve Thank you for your advice. Following your suggestion I found out that `<li>...<\li>` is actually there. It was hiding behind an image (Note: This is a partial view inside _Layout.cshtml where I have placed a top company logo image - I should have paid attention to that). So I needed to adjust the view content properly. For the interest of other readers of this post, you may want to convert your comment to a response with little bit of details explaining the possible cause of the issue. And, I'll mark that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I thought it has something to do with the content inside a code block not rendering without explicit @ symbol. But that shouldn't happen for html tags.

Then I thought the tag might have been rendered and is hidden by some style or just not showing due to nav bar not properly structured. Turns out that it was hidden by a logo image for OP's case.